# Problems with dependencies after setting up go dep

Tags: go, dependency-management, godeps

My project is located in `$GOPATH/src/smp-cloudupload`

I can run `dep init` without errors.
After that I cant compile the project anymore. One of the errors:

```
main/scs/scsApiGateway.go:5:2: cannot find package "_/home/dev/go/src/smp-cloudupload/vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go" in any of:
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/_/home/dev/go/src/smp-cloudupload/vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go (from $GOROOT)
/home/dev/go/src/_/home/dev/go/src/smp-cloudupload/vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go (from $GOPATH)
```

I am new to GO and I have a feeling, that there are either issues with my project structure or the GOPATH. The shown path is wrong. The correct path is: `/home/dev/go/src/smp-cloudupload/vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Output of `echo $GOPATH`:
dev@dev-VirtualBox:~/go/src/smp-cloudupload/main$ echo $GOPATH

```
/home/dev/go
```

I have no idea why there is a underscore in the path. The actual path of my project contains no underscores

Comment: Run "echo $GOPATH" and lets make sure that is correct

Comment: why do you have an underbar in front of that package path ?

Comment: I added the answers to the first posting. I have no idea why there is a underscore.

Comment: What are the imports for the file `scsApiGateway.go`. The error shows a problem with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is resolved now. I was running into this problem:
https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/issues/602

After reading this:
https://thenewstack.io/understanding-golang-packages/

I setup my project structure as follows:

```
/home/dev/go/src/smp-cloudupload
    pkg 
    src
        main
        somepackage
        vendor
```

And it seems to work